# Buttons are not showing any color.. even the default ones

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button, android-styles

The buttons are not showing the correct style or color, see below. This is the `xml` file.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/test_root_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:id="@+id/option_1"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="Option 1"
        android:text="option 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:id="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="Option 2"
        android:text="option 2"
        android:layout_below="@id/option_1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/option_3"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="Option 3"
        android:text="option 3"
        android:layout_below="@id/option_2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/option_4"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="Option 4"
        android:text="option 4"
        android:layout_below="@id/option_3"/>
```

I have never had this kind of problem before.. I have also tried on different versions of  android.. same result

**this is a screenshot of those four buttons:**
 [image]

Comment: Have you defined a custom Button style in your styles.xml file?

Comment: no.. i am using..... Button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));   ...........to respond to an onclicklistener

Comment: What happens if you start a new project and add a Button? Do you get the normal gray background? There must be something relevant in your code that you're not giving us.

Comment: then paste you java code ,so that we can help you

Comment: when i start a new project  the buttons are created with the xml code.. and the only use of these buttons is i use ... button.setText and with an onClickListener i use... Button.setBackgroundColor()....even at the start of app where is only use Button.setText().... the default effects of the buttons dont show up

Comment: The screenshot your adding is not the same as the XML, since in the XML you are hard coding the text "option 1" etc. With that said, something is happening in your code that we are not seeing. The XML maybe relevant, but it looks ok. I would guess your doing somehting in  the java code or the main style of your activity, application

Comment: If it's not the "Button.setBackgroundColor()" that is messed up, like your referencing some invisible color, then it's your main style in the manifest. What is your app main style? Post the manifest please. If that is still not issue, then it could be that your have changed the main default appstyle somehow. That style should be write protected. But Android Studio is very good in doing background changes in a blink a click.

Comment: What i meant is the theme, It's called theme look here --> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Theme

Comment: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>`    This is my app theme.. its not the setBackground color function.. because the button style is not visible even at startup

Comment: Edit your original post to include your Java code.

Comment: i solved the problem..........can anyone tell me what btn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);                                    this sets the color to?

Comment: i copied and paste your xml code in my project and it is looking like normal button in preview. 

May be you are setting the background and text of the button in Java file that is creating problem.


btn.setBackgroundResource() is using to set the drawable file to button background if you want to customise the button background.

Comment: @GauravSharma Post the answer to your question and mark it as solved. Don't post the answer as an comment. We need to close this question